# Return to a previous page after redirecttoaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It's rather complicated to explain but I'll try if there's anything unclear feel free to ask.

I have a page on which I'm editting a dbcontext object through the View of his model(automatically created after making a Model and adding a Dbcontext). However there's also a possibility to contact an external source(LinkedIn) to retrieve this particular information. Because of this I put this link on my page in which the object is being edited: `@Html.ActionLink("Login with LinkedIn", "AuthenticateToLinkedIn", "LinkedIn")`

however when I return to the edit page with this code:

```
int userid1 = Convert.ToInt32(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
List<Person> test = (from p in db.Persons where p.userid == userid1 select p).ToList();

//go back to the original page.
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Person", test[0].ID);
```

It throws an exception that the object is already being modified. This is logical as it most likely saves the earlier page in the memory(I assume my webpage does this not me in my code) thus he thinks the same object is loaded twice which means the object will be conflicted. How could I possibly prevent this though? I was thinking perhaps returning to the original page or a redirect through another page. What are your thoughts on this? And how should I do that because I honestly have no clue how to access the cache or something like that.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to either interpret the problem or suggest a solution. You need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: well the problem is rather complicated and I honestly don't have a clue how I can make it more clear...

Comment: Then unfortunately nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: well.. what part is unclear though? what information are you missing?

Comment: As per the link I posted, the complete (but minimal) code to reproduce the problem. *I have a page on which I'm editting a dbcontext object through the View his model* is not a clear statement of what your code is doing. All I know from reading your question is that you're accessing both a database and an external API, something isn't working and you're somehow "saving a page in memory," though it's not clear what that means. That's not a lot to go off.

Comment: You know when you make a object in the MVC example right? with DbContext added etc? You can automatically let it create Views... I'm using the Edit view of that automatically produced 'Edit' page or is that also too unclear? and I've specified now that I'm not the 1 saving it in the memory but the server or browser... Sadly I can't paste all the code to reproduce it because the problem would be 2 pages long...

Comment: I'll have a go at this. You're displaying an edit page. Editing what? a User?  On the edit page there is a link to LinkedIn - Why? Are you using oauth or something to log in to your application? Once that's done, you're returning to the edit page but an error is thrown. Is that a correct summary?

Comment: Yes I am displaying an edit page of a profile with information like Name, Skills, Place of Residence etc. On the Edit page is indeed a link to the LinkedIn API for usability as with the LinkedIn login you can extract the information and the data gets filled in automatically instead of you having to type in the information in the textboxes yourself. The login method that LinkedIn uses is OAuth. The data gets filled in correctly and everything, it throws me an error however when i try to submit the page and save the new data of the person in the database

Comment: because the database thinks the data of the person on the edit page is still being modified